# Image URLs show as separate pages on search engine results

Tags: url

Many of the image URLs of my website show as separate pages on Google search results. See the photo.
By the way, these image URLs show as an orphan page in Ahrefs's website audit tool.

I checked other websites with the command site:example.com on Google, but none of them have an image URL as a separate page in Google search results.

Is it ordinary that the image url shows as a separate page on search results?
How do I solve it?

I couldn't find any solution for it.
I appreciate any response.Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgoiL.jpg)